# How can I remove this shadow-root custom button from an HTML video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, shadow-dom

I have used a slide show on my web site. There are a couple of images and a video. I have not enabled any shadow elements or controls for this video, however there is a custom button to open it externally and I cannot disable it in any ways.

I have tried different JS scripts to attach a shadow and set the mode on closed, but I get the error that this video element cannot have an attached shadow.

[Here's the button I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fznjE.jpg)

An example script that I have used:

```
function makeShadowTree(shadowClose) {
    var root = shadowClose.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});  
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.slides--i').forEach(makeShadowTree);
});
```

```html
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slides--i" id="slide--1"></div>
    <div class="slides--i" id="slide--2"></div>
    <video autoplay muted loop class="slides--i" id="slide--video">
        <source src="img/slides/slide-03-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot add a Shadow DOM on an element that already hosts its own, user-agent Shadow DOM, for example the <video> element.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Edit the question and add the HTML structures that define the slide show. What video viewer are you using? (an HTML5 <video/> element??) Probably there are CSS addressable Properties that can switch of the Button. Browsers like Firefox and Chrome allow you to inspect the DOM. You can use them "study" the components structure.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I added the HTML code to the question. I have inspected the reason this button appears and found a div outside the body having #shadow-root open. I have researched quite a lot and tried different methods to prevent this from happening all of which were unsuccessful. Do you have any ideas on how I can prevent that button from appearing?

Comment: There are classes `slides` and `slides--i`  which might define CSS that add the button (after:: or before:: or ??). Is this CSS written by yourself or do you use a library?  The shadow DOM is probably added by the video element (see comment of @Supersharp) or it can be added by the Slides library if you use one. If you also add the CSS for `slidess` and `slides--i` I possibly find a hint. If you havent written it yourself, give me a link to the Library project.

Comment: And there must be javascript code that initializes and controlls the slide show. This could also be interesting. ;-)

Comment: NB: The ability to show/hide the control buttons -with the `control` attribute- will depend on the browser.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I haven't used a library and no JS code initialized it. But I suppose I've found what the problem was. I realized that this doesn't happen in browsers other than Opera. Apparently it is  a new feature of this browser for videos longer than 15 seconds. But I couldn't find a way to stop it. The only way is to use a video with less than 15 seconds of length.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you for the info.  That might be an issue for me too in the future. So I try to investigate a little bit over the next few days. Of cause, I let you know if I could find a work around.

Comment: Et voila:  https://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2016/04/opera-beta-update-video-pop/ a first hint.

Comment: One more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096663/how-to-remove-the-pop-up-video-in-opera  But I've nothing found to switch it off from the page itselfs.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Yeah, I've come across these pages but no workarounds are suggested there. I'll also keep you updated if I find any.